# Properly Parsing Specific Output from Terminal in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have made a simple program that outputs text to the terminal (stdout) and another program that takes that text and parses it to match my preferred output.

The first program just prints these lines to stdout:

`620_ha_1 # Version: Fortigate-620B v4.0,build0271,100330 (MR2)
Virus-DB: 11.00643(2010-03-31 17:
Extended DB: 11.00643(2010-03-31 17:
Extreme DB: 0.00000(2003-01-01 00:
IPS-DB: 2.00778(2010-03-31 12:
FortiClient application signature package: 1.167(2010-04-01 10:
Serial-Number: FG600B3908600705`

My second program then captures that output and parses it:

```
import subprocess
import re

infoDict = dict()

# Prints were purely for my testing purposes
process = subprocess.Popen(['python','-u', 'output.py'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
while True:
    output = process.stdout.readline().decode()
    if output == '' and process.poll() is not None:
        break
    if output:
        rmHost = re.sub(".*?#", "", output.strip())
        versionInfo = re.split(": ", rmHost)
        # print("VERSION: " + versionInfo[0] + ": " + versionInfo[1])
        fields = re.split(".*?#|: ", output.strip())
        name = fields[0]
        data = fields[1]
        # print("name: " + name)
        # print("data: " + data)
```

Almost everything works correctly, except I don't know how to properly handle the first line while in the loop. I am trying to completely get rid of the `620_ha_1 #` portion of the output. My eventual goal is to store this all in a dict where `name` acts as the keys and `data` acts as the values.

**TL;DR**

*How do I properly parse the first line of the output shown so that it matches the same format as the following lines which will allow me to store it in a dict.*

**Thank you!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The Plan

The game plan is to strip off the leading text, up to and including the pound sign. Then parsing will be easier.

## The Code

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/q/49785215/459745
import re
import pprint

output = """620_ha_1 # Version: Fortigate-620B v4.0,build0271,100330 (MR2)
Virus-DB: 11.00643(2010-03-31 17:
Extended DB: 11.00643(2010-03-31 17:
Extreme DB: 0.00000(2003-01-01 00:
IPS-DB: 2.00778(2010-03-31 12:
FortiClient application signature package: 1.167(2010-04-01 10:
Serial-Number: FG600B3908600705
"""

# Regular expression to extract the keys/values from output. The
# re.VERBOSE flag allows for comment inside the regular expression
key_value_pattern = re.compile("""
    \s*      # White spaces (including new lines) preceding the key
    ([^:]+)  # The key: anything but the colon
    :        # The colon itself
    (.+)     # The value
    """, flags=re.VERBOSE)

# Remove the text up to and including the pound sign
output = output.partition('#')[-1]
infoDict = dict(key_value_pattern.findall(output))

# Show
pprint.pprint(infoDict)
```

## Output

```
{'Extended DB': ' 11.00643(2010-03-31 17:',
 'Extreme DB': ' 0.00000(2003-01-01 00:',
 'FortiClient application signature package': ' 1.167(2010-04-01 10:',
 'IPS-DB': ' 2.00778(2010-03-31 12:',
 'Serial-Number': ' FG600B3908600705',
 'Version': ' Fortigate-620B v4.0,build0271,100330 (MR2)',
 'Virus-DB': ' 11.00643(2010-03-31 17:'}
```

## Notes

- The code is not that long, I strike for being verbose to help explaining how things work
- `str.partition` split the string into 3 parts: before the pound sign, the pound sign, and after the pound sign. We are only interested in the part after the pound sign.
- The `.findall` method will return a list of (key, value), which is perfect for making a dictionary

Comment: This was very helpful and straightforward to understand. Thank you for your help!